# How do I set up autocomplete in powershell 2.0?

Tags: forms, powershell, autocomplete, powershell-2.0

I have a drop down menu that's populated by a CSV file. I had to change my code around to make it work with v2. The last thing I can't figure out is autocomplete. I'd like to be able to type in the listbox and have it suggest some options from the list. It works fine in v3, but not v2.

Here are the parts that matter...

```
$filecheck = "$dir\Apps\Customers.csv"
If(Test-Path -path $filecheck) {
    $Customers = Import-CSV "$dir\Apps\Customers.csv" -Header $headers
    $List = $customers | Select-Object -Expand name | where {$_ -ne ""} | where {$_ -ne "Name"} | Sort-Object
}

ForEach ($Items in $List) {

    $companybox.Items.Add($Items)

}

$companybox.AutoCompleteSource = 'CustomSource'
$companybox.AutoCompleteMode = 'SuggestAppend'
$List | % {$companybox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange($_) }

$Form1.Controls.Add($companybox)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked around but haven't found much for v2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. I added -STA to the batch file that runs the script to change it to Single Thread Apartment.

My batch file now looks like this to run the script in STA as administrator...

```
SET Dir=%~dp0
SET PSPath=%Dir%Script.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-STA -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PSPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Another option is to put this in the PS script...

```
if ([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ApartmentState -eq [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::MTA)
{
powershell.exe -Sta -File $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
return
}
```

However, the second option broke the code I have to hide the console window on startup.